¿Cómo representar en el argumento "hue" una columna filtrada en concreto?
En el ejercicio me piden lo siguiente: Crea un programa que muestre la evolución de los casos confirmados y de pacientes recuperados de coronavirus, en las diferentes provincias de España, durante el primer trimestre de 2021. Lo puedo hacer tanto en dos gráficos (gráfico de confirmados por provincia trimestre 2021 y gráfico de recuperados) o en un único gráfico; yo lo estaba intentado hacer en dos separados.
En el eje X he puesto los tres meses correspondientes y en el eje Y no me queda claro si debería poner la columna "Confirmed" o si centrarlo en los valores filtrados por provincia de España (que es lo que he usado). Entiendo que para representar las provincias, las puedo meter en el argumento "hue" y que cada una sea una línea, pero no sé si como lo he expresado en el código sería correcto, y por otro lado, no sé si al no poner el argumento "palette" se ponen los colores solos, ya que hay bastantes provincias.
Por último, me he fijado que hay una fila "unknown" común a los tres dataframes, que no sé si se podría eliminar para no alterar el gráfico.



import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

df_1 = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-01-2021.csv", sep = ",")
df_2 = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-02-2021.csv", sep = ",")
df_3 = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-03-2021.csv", sep = ",")

df_1 = df_1.loc [df_1 ["Country_Region"] == "Spain", ["Confirmed"]]
df_2 = df_2.loc [df_2 ["Country_Region"] == "Spain", ["Confirmed"]]
df_3 = df_3.loc [df_3 ["Country_Region"] == "Spain", ["Confirmed"]]

sns.lineplot (x = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"], y = [df_1, df_2, df_3], hue = ["Country_Region" == "Spain"]).set_title("Casos confirmados de coronavirus por primer trimestre 2021")
plt.show() 


  


Sería de más ayuda si pusieras los csv como texto

Hola @Christian buenas tardes, creo que no sé cómo hacer eso. Me podrías ayudar y así ya lo sé para la siguiente vez? Muchas gracias!

Solo copia y pega el contenido de tus csv, luego yo me encargo de formatearlo bonito

@Christian Creo que eso es lo que he hecho. Antes hacía una captura y la subía y como me comentaron que mejor pegando el contenido, como me decías tú, pego los datos y ya está. Creía que lo estaba haciendo correctamente jeje. Quizás es copiar/pegar y ya está? que sale todo el contenido seguido digamos?

@AlvaroGarciaLinares el código lo estás agregando muy bien, son los datos de los csv los que son imagenes y eso dificulta la reproducción.  Los archivos csv son archivos de texto plano, para agregarlos a una pregunta abrelos con un editor de texto (tipo notepad) en vez de ¿excel?, seleccionas y copias las filas que desees y pegas el texto aquí tal cual. Luego lo formateas igual que haces con el código. No se verá bonito, pero eso hace que reproducir el código sea super simple sin necesidad de recurrir a OCR o a crear un conjunto de datos por nosotros mismos. Saludos.

buenas tardes @FJSevilla , he abierto el csv con "textedit" en mac y me sale un archivo de este estilo: FIPS,Admin2,Province_State,Country_Region,Last_Update,Lat,Long_,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered,Active,Combined_Key,Incident_Rate,Case_Fatality_Ratio
,,,Afghanistan,2021-01-02 05:22:33,33.93911,67.709953,51526,2191,41727,0,Afghanistan,0.0,4.2522221790940495
,,,Albania,2021-01-02 05:22:33,41.1533,20.1683,58316,1181,33634,23501,Albania,2026.4090624782818,2.025173194320598. A esto se le puede aplicar formato como al código y así vosotros lo podéis manejar mejor, verdad?

@AlvaroGarciaLinares exacto, ese es el contenido del .csv (Comma-separated values) como ves es simple texto plano. Simplemente pega el texto en la pregunta y formatealo como haces con el código y ya está. Ten en cuenta para futuras preguntas que si tu csv es muy largo es posible que no lo puedas agregar todo, generalmente no hace falta, con que agregues la primera linea (si el csv tiene encabezado) y unas cuantas filas de datos suele ser suficiente, lo importante es que con los datos que aportes se pueda reproducir el problema/error que planteas.

Para empezar debemos de juntar todos los dataframes que tienes, esto lo puedes hacer usando el método pd.concat, lo que hice yo es usar un OCR para analizar una tu imagen y duplicar esa infromación (cambiando los meses) para tener los 3 dataframes y ponerlo directamente en uno.
Una vez ya teniendo todo en un solo datframe tenemos que hacer un pre-procesamiento de este para eliminar la fila Unknow ya que no aporta nada.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# nos quedamos con las columnas que nos importan
df_1 = df.loc[:,["Province_State", "Last_Update", "Confirmed", "Recovered"]]

print(df_1.shape)

# reemplazamos por nan donde aparezca Unknow
df_1 = df_1.replace(to_replace="Unknown", value=np.nan)
df_1.dropna(inplace=True) # eliminamos los nan

print(df_1.shape)


Para poder graficar la evolución de los casos confirmados y pacientes recuperados por estado de España tendríamos que agrupar según el estado e ir viendo los meses para crear una gráfica por estado, para esto opté por usar un multi-index en pandas en vez de un gruopby, esto por que consideré más fácil.
Lo que hace un Hierarchical indexing (MultiIndex) es organizar los datos en una jerarquía, donde los índices superiores agrupan los datos en categorías más amplias y los índices inferiores proporcionan detalles más específicos. En nuestro caso lo utilizamos para organizarlo según el estado y la fecha.
df_1.set_index(['Province_State', 'Last_Update'], inplace=True)
df_1.sort_index(inplace=True)
df_1

Ahora con esto ya podemos graficar de una forma muy fácil
ax = df_1.unstack(level=0).loc[:, ["Confirmed"]].plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, rot=0, figsize=(14, 12), layout=(8, 5))
plt.tight_layout()

Para "desagrupar" (pivotar) los datos organizados usamos unstack indicando el nivel que queremos pivotar, en este caso pivotamos el nivel 0 que corresponde al estado y en base a ello ya graficamos.

En mi caso como use los mismos registro cambiando solo la fecha salen las barras iguales, en tu caso al tener distintos datos en Recovered y Confirmed saldrán barras diferentes.
Si quieres puedes graficar los confirmados y recuperados en distintas graficas
# pivotar multi-indexes
data = df_1.unstack(level=0)

# Graficar confirmados
ax = data.loc[:, ["Confirmed"]].plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, rot=0, figsize=(14, 12), layout=(5, 4))
plt.tight_layout()

# Graficar recuperados
ax = data.loc[:, ["Recovered"]].plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, rot=0, figsize=(14, 12), layout=(5, 4))
plt.tight_layout()


Buenas tardes @Christian , muchas gracias por tu explicación, es muy completa. Voy a analizarla a ver si entiendo bien lo que me expones, ya que creo que se me escapa un poco el nivel ahora mismo.. jeje. Entiendo que la idea que mas o menos tenía yo, que era concatenar los 3 df para poder usarlo como "data" en el lineplot, y sacar por separado el valor de confirmados por mes y luego en "hue" que saliera cada provincia, para que dibujara en un mismo grafico "x" líneas de diferentes colores, no es acertada verdad?. Por si de esa manera podría ser más fácil para mi

No es que no sea acertado, depende de lo que quieras dar a entender con las gráficas y que tan detallado quieres que sea, con el enfoque que propuse tienes un buen punto de partida :D

buenos días @Christian , creo haber entendido tu explicación :) pero sigo sin conseguir resolver en un sólo gráfico con los casos confirmados para que salgan todas las provincias en el argumento "hue" . No sé si podrías ayudarme a resolverlo de esa manera, Un saludo y muchas gracias!

buenas tardes @FJSevilla, no sé si me podrías ayudar tú a realizarlo de la forma que exponía en el comentario anterior. Un saludo y muchas gracias!

@AlvaroGarciaLinares en un solo grafico quieres poner todas las ciudades no?

Hola @Christian sí, plasmarlo en un único gráfico con las distintas provincias en una leyenda "hue". Un saludo y muchas gracias!

¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme? Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Buenas @Christian, sigo sin encontrar la solución, no sé si podrías ayudarme, voy a intentar explicar lo mejor posible lo que necesito. Debería hacer una gráfica con los nombres de los tres meses en el eje X y con los valores de confirmados por provincia en el eje Y. Una leyenda de "Confirmados" en el eje Y y "Meses" en el eje X (por ejemplo). Una leyenda mediante argumento "hue" que muestre cada provincia y plasme el valor por mes en el gráfico, de tal manera que por ejemplo Madrid, sea rojo y se vea la evolución de los tres valores, andalucía en azul (los colores da un poco igual). Gracias!
